# Print 25 usernames on the system starting in reverse alphabetic order. Print only the usernames,

Tags: users, printing

how to  Print 25 usernames on the system starting in reverse alphabetic order. Print only the
usernames, nothing else. You should get the information from the /etc/passwd file.? in UNIX Command

Comment: Since this is clearly a homework exercise, the first response should be "What you have tried so far?"

Comment: Every question you've asked so far has been a homework question, hasn't it?

Comment: lp last -R -20      its  a project for school  thanks for the help

Comment: This may be relevant: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy to do your homework for you, less competition in the job market:

```
#  cat /etc/passwd|awk -F\: '{ print $1 }'| sort | head -20
```

Comment: i really appreciate your help :) and  for all off you too